# why would an hprof file have a much smaller size than the amount of memory given to the jvm

Tags: java, out-of-memory, hprof

Our code runs with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag so we get an hprof file on OOM. 
Recently I got such a file from an installation, I opened it with Eclipse memory analyzer (MAT) and I can see the total size is 46MB, how can it be if the process was started with -Xmx1024m???

Should not the size be much much closer to the max allocated size??

This is with jdk1.6.

EDIT: ok now I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808270/memory-dump-much-smaller-than-available-memory) and indeed a PermGen space issue could be the reason, as my process has been up for 23 days. I create new threads (that end properly as far as I know) very often, once per second maybe. Anybody knows if I could confirm this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you failed to create a very large object. i.e. the object which you failed to create is not in the dump.

Comment: yes I thought of that but no other hint points at this...see my edit, I found a relevant question here

Comment: The simplest way to confirm the cause is to read the original exception. e.g "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" or "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory" Also the stack trace should indicate the operation which failed which should give you a clue.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't catch any exception

Comment: Is there an OOME object in the heap dump? Can you read the message for it?

Comment: No, I searched the heap with a OQL query 'SELECT toString(s) FROM java.lang.OutOfMemoryError s' and got 0 results.

Comment: I have opened a new more specific question on thread creation

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, In my case I am pretty sure it was due to a permgen, but what you mentioned could be also the cause so I'll accept your reply